# Firebase cloud functions: How to wait for a document to be created and update it afterwards

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Here is the situation:

1. I have collections 'lists', 'stats', and 'posts'.
2. From frontend, there is a scenario where the user uploads a content. The frontend function creates a document under 'lists', and after the document is created, it creates another document under 'posts'.
3. I have a CF that listens to creation of a document under 'lists' and create a new document under 'stats'.
4. I have a CF that listens to creation of a document under 'posts' and update the document created under 'stats'.

The intended order of things to happen is 2->3->4. However, apparently, step 4 is triggered before step 3, and so there is no relevant document under 'stats' to update, thus throwing an error.

Is there a way to make the function wait for the document creation under 'stats' and update only after it is created? I thought about using setTimeout() for the function in step 4, but guess there might be a better way.

Below is the code that I am using for steps 3 and 4. Can someone advise? Thanks!

```
//This listens to a creation of a document under 'lists' and creates a new document 
//with the same document ID under 'stats'.

exports.statsCreate = functions.firestore
.document('lists/{listid}').onCreate((snap,context)=>{
    const listidpath=snap.ref.path;
    const pathfinder=listidpath.split('/');
    const listid=pathfinder[pathfinder.length-1];
    return db.collection('stats').doc(listid).set({
        postcount:0,
    })
})



//This listens to a creation of a document under 'posts' and updates the corresponding
// document under 'stats'. There is a field under 'posts' with the list ID to make this possible. 
// How do I make sure the update operation happens only after the document is actually there?

exports.statsUpdate = functions.firestore
.document('posts/{postid}').onCreate((snap,context)=>{
    const data=snap.data();
    return db.collection('stats').doc(data.listid).update({
        postcount:admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can see at least two "easy" solutions:

- Solution #1: In your front end, set a listener to the to-be-created `stat` document (with `onSnapshot()`), and only create the `post` document when the `stat` one has been created. Note however that this solution will not work if the user **does not have read access right** to the `posts` collection.
- Solution #2: Use the ["retry on failure" option](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/retries#enabling_and_disabling_retries) for background Cloud Functions. Within your `statsUpdate` Cloud Function you intentionally throw an exception if the `stat` doc is not found => The CF will be retried until the `stat` doc is created.

---

A third solution would be to use a Callable Cloud Function, called from your front-end. This Callable Cloud Function would write the three docs in the following order: list, stat and post. Then the `statsUpdate` Cloud Function would be triggered in the background (or you could include its business logic in the Callable Cloud Function as well).

One of the drawbacks of this solution is that the Cloud Function may encounter some cold start effect. In this case, from an end-user perspective, the process may take more time than the abonne solutions. **However** note that you can [specify a minimum number of container instances to be kept warm](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/manage-functions#min-max-instances) and ready to serve requests.

---

PS: Note that in the `statsCreate` CF, you don't need to extract the `listid` with:

```
const listidpath=snap.ref.path;
const pathfinder=listidpath.split('/');
const listid=pathfinder[pathfinder.length-1];
```

Just do:

```
const listid = context.params.listid;
```

The [`context`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/cloud_functions_.eventcontext#params) parameter provides information about the Cloud Function's execution.